# What is the proper way to use @lombok.Cleanup here?

Tags: java, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

Earlier the code was like this -

```
    try {
         some other code
         ......
         ......
            ByteArrayInputStream annoBais = new ByteArrayInputStream(annoBytes);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(annoBais);
            InputStream annoStream = dis;
            inputRecord.put("XMLStream", annoStream);
            MappedRecord resultMappedRecord = (MappedRecord)interaction.execute(interactionSpec,inputRecord);
            HashMap mappedAnnotIds =  (HashMap)resultMappedRecord.get(("ResultHashMap").toString());
            annoStream.close(); //closed here
            annoBais.close();   // closed here
            dis.close();     // closed here
         ......
         ......
         some more code 
        }
```

I changed it to -

```
 try {
some other code
......
......                
@lombok.Cleanup ByteArrayInputStream annoBais = new ByteArrayInputStream(annoBytes);
@lombok.Cleanup DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(annoBais);
@lombok.Cleanup InputStream annoStream = dis; 
inputRecord.put("XMLStream", annoStream);
MappedRecord resultMappedRecord (MappedRecord)interaction.execute(interactionSpec,inputRecord);
HashMap mappedAnnotIds = (HashMap)resultMappedRecord.get(("ResultHashMap").toString());
......
......
some more code 
}
```

Is @lombok.Cleanup going to have the same scope ? Will it close at the same place where it was earlier being closed manually ? If not, how can I close it in a way that it still has the same scope ?

Comment: If you are on Java7, why do you even need lombok? Use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)!

Comment: Otherwise I'll have to use nested try blocks if I am using try with resources. Thought of using @lombok.Cleanup because my project is using lombok anyway.

Comment: No, you don't need to nest anything. Try-with-resources supports handling of multiple resources at once.

Comment: So would it be wise to instantiate the three in the first try block itself ?

Comment: because in the code they are initialised later on

Comment: Also using try with resources is causing me to handle few other exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to use @lombok.Cleanup here is by not using lombok; Java7 solves this with [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Eg, with your code:

```
     some other code
     ......
     ......

     try (  ByteArrayInputStream annoBais = new ByteArrayInputStream(annoBytes);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(annoBais) ) {
        InputStream annoStream = dis;
        inputRecord.put("XMLStream", annoStream);
        MappedRecord resultMappedRecord = (MappedRecord)interaction.execute(interactionSpec,inputRecord);
        HashMap mappedAnnotIds =  (HashMap)resultMappedRecord.get(("ResultHashMap").toString());
     }
     //  annoBais & dis get closed here.
     //  Note: annoStream is an alias of dis, not a separate resource.
     ......
     ......
     some more code
```

Of course, this code needs to be surrounded by a `try {} catch () {}` block, or your method must declare that it `throws` the required exceptions.

Using "try with resources" does not cause you to have to handle additional exceptions.  You always need to handle all checked exceptions, either by catching them or declaring your methods throws them.

Comment: but this would lead me to use nested try blocks, isn't it ?

Comment: @ShubhamPandey, no, you can add a `catch` to the try-with-resources block itself, and that catch block will act as handler for potential `IOException`s

Comment: A `try { ... }` statement must end with either one or more `catch ( ... ) {  }` clauses, or a `finally { ... }` clause, or both.  If it was not terminated by any of these, the `try` statement wouldn't be doing anything.  In contrast with this, a try-with-resources statement, `try ( ... ) { ... }` does not require `catch` or `finally` clauses, because a try-with-resources statement _already does something useful_; it ensures [`AutoClosable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) resources are closed when the block is exited, regardless of how it is exited.

Comment: Having a `try` or a try-with-resources statement does not require that you immediately catch __all__ checked exceptions that the protected block can throw.  You can delegate some (or all) checked exceptions to the surrounding code, or to the caller.  For example, you could have an outer `try { ... } catch (IOException ex) { ... }` block, and use a try-with-resources statement without any `catch` clauses inside the try block.  Or you could declare the method `throws IOException` and use the try-with-resources statement without any `catch` clauses.  Or the try-with-resources can catch it itself.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
@lombok.Cleanup ByteArrayInputStream annoBais = new ByteArrayInputStream(annoBytes);
@lombok.Cleanup DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(annoBais);
@lombok.Cleanup InputStream annoStream = dis;
```

all three resources get closed at the closing brace in reverse order of their declaration. AFAIK, that's exactly the same as with try-with-resources.

`@Cleanup` works even when some of the close statement throw. That's the same, too.

It works even with Java 6, but you really shouldn't be using Java 6.

`@Cleanup` has a superior syntax, but that's subjective. I'm stopping using it as try-with-resources is a build-in feature sure to be supported forever or alike.

> Also using try with resources is causing me to handle few other exceptions.

Definitely not, this must be the same, too. Note that 99% of the time, you should add the exceptions to the throws clause or wrap and re-throw them.

Note that

```
@lombok.Cleanup InputStream annoStream = dis;
```

makes no sense as you're not acquiring a new resource. So

```
 InputStream annoStream = dis;
```

would be better as there's nothing new to close. Even better would be to ditch `annoStream` as it hardly ever makes sense to have two variables for one thing.

Luckily, calling `close` multiple times is harmless.